# Optical character recognition on the iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, image-processing, core-graphics

Is it possible on an iPhone app to take a picture and extract an string from the picture?  We'd like to make our app to look for a serial number on a database (very long number) without the user having to type it.

Is there any Cocoa/Objective-C API for this or any C/C++ library that can be used in an iPhone app?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a look at the [tesseract-ocr](http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/) project. It's not actually made to use on an iPhone but I believe others have made great use of it on the iPhone.

Here is a [demo](http://github.com/nolanbrown/Tesseract-iPhone-Demo) that makes use of the tesseract ocr engine.

Comment: Thank you for this.  The demo is crashing on my test phone but definitively this points in the right track.

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for something similar and came across [ABBYY's mobileOCR solution](http://www.abbyy.com/mobileOCR) 
I've not used it yet and have no idea how much it is but you should be able to integrate it into your app by all accounts.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try the tesseract-ocr first but this one looks like a good candidate if we decide to go with a commercial solution.

Answer (score 1):

I have this in my bookmarks: http://code.google.com/p/zxing/
It has iPhone, Android and Java code to deal with image capture and bar codes.
I haven't test it yet.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another implementation of Tesseract on the iPhone: http://robertcarlsen.net/dev/pocket-ocr

Answer (score 0):

Tesseract-OCR now has iOS version:[Tesseract-OCR-iOS](https://github.com/gali8/Tesseract-OCR-iOS)