# How to read the text from an image in iphone

Tags: iphone, image, text, ocr

i want to read text in an image how to do that...

Thanks

Comment: rockey do you mean taking a photograph of a document and working out what has been written there? If so then see the two answers that Jeff and Phlibbo posted. If not then try to explain exactly what youre trying to do and it might be easier to help you.

Comment: This is effectively a duplicate of your earlier question: [How to scan a thing from a iphone application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4045908/how-to-scan-a-thing-from-a-iphone-application).  You should just refine that one, rather than asking a new question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Optical character recognition on the iPhone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3944983/optical-character-recognition-on-the-iphone)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you’re asking about is called [OCR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_character_recognition), and it isn’t as simple as you might think. Luckily, there is at least one [open-source effort](http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/) to do it.

Answer (score 2):

You need an OCR library, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/964181/is-there-any-open-source-ocr-project-for-the-iphone-out-there) for further information. For a more specific answer, you might want to post a more specific question.